# Bootstrap carousel image is not being showed responsive, inside RenderBody()

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

I am trying to create carousel responsive image inside the index home page which are being displayed inside the common layout page. But when I reduce the height carousel-item div, full image is not being showed in index html. How can I show the full image as responsive ,  even if I reduce the height of  carousel-item div.?

My code given below

1. _Layout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MyCompany</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid icon-top py-4 px-5">
        <div class="row">
             
        </div>

    </div>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MyCompany</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Our Project</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="body-container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container" id>
            &copy; 2021 - MyCompany - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/all.js"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

2. Index.cshtml

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<section id="home-heading">
    <div id="MyCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-1 active">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item  carousel-image-2">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-3">

            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#MyCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#MyCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- INFO SECTION -->
<section id="info" class="py-3>
    <div class=" container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 align-self-center">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate eveniet blanditiis incidunt iusto
                corrupti illum cum laudantium ex sequi amet. ssfsdfs fjjerhehr uiewruhweuiruiewruyhyuewiry iweuyr
                ryewiuryiweuy. uieeryewi iuweriwe yb 7weyr7ewy87r7ywe8ry8wer8 we87r y87we78r7we8r
                7we87rwe87r87wer8werweuewof
                w8ueuwe88ur9we8r </p>
            <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Learn More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/laptop.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

3. Site.css

```css
 

a.navbar-brand {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
}

#body-container {
    /*  */
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}


/* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */

a {
    color: #0366d6;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}


/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */

html {
    font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

.border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: inherit;
}


/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 60px;
    /* Vertically center the text there */
}

.icon-top {
    background-color: chocolate;
}

.navbar .nav-link {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    text-align: right !important;
    padding-left: 1rem !important;
    padding-right: 1rem !important;
}

.navbar .nav-item.active {
    border-left: #444 3px solid;
}

.carousel-item {
    height: 800px;
}

.carousel-image-1 {
    background: url('../img/banner-1.jpeg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-image-2 {
    background: url('../img/banner-2.jpeg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-image-3 {
    background: url('../img/banner-3.jpeg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

With Many Thanks
Pol

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Layout page.

```
@RenderSection("style", required: false)
```

Now add your Carousel code to any View page. under`@section style{ "your bootstrap carousel code"}` so for that, you will successfully show your carousel where you want. also, the carousel fits the full image as responsive.

```
@section style{

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="margin-top:-15px">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" style="background-color: gray; height: 550px; width: 100%;" src="~/images/family1.jpeg" alt="Img1" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Image 1</h3>
                <p>A happy image</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" style="background-color: gray; height: 550px; width: 100%;" src="~/images/family1.jpeg" alt="Img2" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Image 2</h3>
                <p>A new image</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" style="background-color: gray; height: 550px; width: 100%;" src="~/images/family1.jpeg" alt="Img3" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Image 3</h3>
                <p>An old image</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

}
```

Comment: I have already added @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false). How can I add style required: false in addition to that of script

Comment: When I change the code , the carousel images  is going to the bottom of other content  page

Comment: @AlanPauil use  ```<style>
        ...
    </style>```for required style in your section script.I think it's will work fine.

Comment: make sure your "Rendersection" above the "Renderbody".

Comment: still not working. the following error is coming "InvalidOperationException: RenderSectionAsync invocation in '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml' is invalid. The section 'style' has already been rendered."

Comment: @AlanPauil please change your "Rendersection" name instead of "style".